# Finding Changes In Matlab Data Stream

Tags: matlab

I currently have a discrete value data stream in column form.

For example;

```
x = [0 0 0 33 33 129 129 255 33 33 0]';
```

Each of these decimal values have a binary representation where each bit represents some description in a table. So for 129 (10000001), bit 0 and 7 have an associated description that I need to look up. This is true for all values in the data stream.

Currently I'm doing the following;

```
z = find(logical(diff(x)));
```

Which provides the locations of the changes in `x`. I then use a for loop to go through z and find where the bits are which equal 1.

```
fault = find(dec2bin(z(i)) == '1');
```

This all works fine, however currently my answers are split into groups of decimal value changes. So the output sees two instances of 33, two of 129, one of 255, and two more of 33. However, on a bit-wise level, something like bit 1 was actually set the entire time. This is what I really want, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way of keep tracking of JUST the bits that were set.

Is there a way to track this more on a bit-wise level so I can see which bits are being set and cleared, instead of breaking into decimal value changes?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Do you want to keep track of the bits that were not changed over the entire sequence, or do you want to keep track of what bits are different or the same between transitions?  Can you show us a concrete numerical / visual example of what it is you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I suppose you want to find for each bit at which positions in the stream it changed. Here's how:

```
bin = dec2bin(x);
nbits = size(bin, 2);
for bit = 1 : nbits
    fprintf('bit %d was changed at:', nbits - bit)
    fprintf(' %d', find(diff(bin(:, bit))))
    fprintf('\n')
end
```

For your example `x`, the output is

```
bit 7 was changed at: 5 8
bit 6 was changed at: 7 8
bit 5 was changed at: 3 5 7 10
bit 4 was changed at: 7 8
bit 3 was changed at: 7 8
bit 2 was changed at: 7 8
bit 1 was changed at: 7 8
bit 0 was changed at: 3 10
```

The trick is to first convert the data into a binary representation and then use `find(diff(...))` to identify changes.